# NSURLRequest Know the URL Type if it is file or link

Tags: url, types, nsurlrequest

I have used a UIWebView in my app and want to download the file. 
I have referred to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377565/how-to-download-files-from-uiwebview-and-open-again)

I wanted to know if there is a way to know if the NSURLRequest is a normal link or is it a link to download a file.

Regards,
Nirav

Answer (score 1):

NSURL has a method 'isFileURL'

```
[request.URL isFileURL]
```