# Allow download of PDFs or Images from iOS or Android app

Tags: android, ios, pdf, webview, download

In my iOS app, I have PDFs shown in a webview that are hosted online. How can I allow users to download/save these PDFs to their devices from within the app?

I also want android users to be able to download the content, but the content is hosted as an image, because android's PDF viewing capabilities were not good. So what do I need to do to allow users to download an image from within the app (also in a webview)?

Comment: Obviously you need to implement sever side logic to give PDF/Images based on request, or from the client (app side), you need to request for PDF/Images depending on OS.

You cannot simply download files from webview wrapper, you need to write some native code to fetch the files from server and save it in device

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377565/how-to-download-files-from-uiwebview-and-open-again check this mate