# moving data from webview into ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I am not sure of how I would achieve the following functionality and was looking for suggestions. I have an Objective-C iOS app that loads a `WebView`. The user has a way to download data within the webview running a JS application. When the user triggers this download, I would like to use the downloaded data and execute a method call in the native code.

Comment: check the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377565/how-to-download-files-from-uiwebview-and-open-again

Comment: @casillas, thanks for your suggested link.  I might be able to use it though in my web app, the data to be passed back to the native app is not available through a URL.  I will have to figure out a way to get the data back   into the native code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to use some kind of Hybrid calls. Once Javascript downloads the file, you should invoke a native app call (with a special schema say iosbridgecall:// from Javascript) and check this schema in shouldStartLoadWithRequest,

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if ([[[request URL] scheme] isEqualToString:@"iosbridgecall"]) {
       //here invoke your Native Method, ex:
       processDownloadedData();
       return NO;
    } else {
      return YES;
    }
}
```