# How can I download files in xls format from UIWEBVIEW?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *) webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *) request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType) navigationType
{
     
    NSString *mimeType = [request valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSLog(@"Content-type: %@", mimeType);
    if(mimeType isEqualToString:@"application/vnd.ms-excel"] )
    {
        NSLog(@"Downloading file!");
       
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377565/how-to-download-files-from-uiwebview-and-open-again ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.